# How to Fix SCNNode Transform Problem with CABasicAnimation in SceneKit in Swift?

Tags: scenekit, cabasicanimation, scnnode

I have a problem. I rotate it but SCNNode returns to its starting position.

Look at the gif please: https://i.ibb.co/X2kz6fK/ezgif-5-d0417c4423.gif

My code:

[image]

Thanks everyone...

Comment: your indicated URL seems not to work properly - are you required to use a CAAnimation? Or could it be something else? Like a SCNaction?

Comment: @ZAY Hello, I changed the image URL. Please check it.

Comment: is your intention to rotate that car around the Y-axis at a specific angle, then it keeps it's final ratation after applying it? (As I asked: Are you "required" to use a CAAnimation?)

Comment: Yes, I want to rotate car in Y-axis. I tried other solutions, but this time, when the north angles such as 350 degrees and 10 degrees came, the vehicle started to turn full circle. For example other solutions:

cubeNode.eularAngles = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: ..., z:0)
cubeNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, angle)
SCNAction.rotate...

These pose a problem for the northern degrees. The vehicle rotates around the y-axis. I can upload the image if you want.

Comment: yes please if you can provide more information, I dont fully understand the point

Comment: I uploaded a video. Check link: http://streamable.com/2ah06c
Here, I used to cubeNode.eulerAngles solution in this video. When going north, when angles such as 355 degrees and 5 degrees come, the vehicle makes a full lap.

Comment: how exactly do you position the car in the scene? is the view in the video from the top Y-up direction (scenekit specific) or from the Z-forward (normal view)? The code how you setup the node could be helpful

Comment: I have uploaded a picture of the codes : https://ibb.co/mST0gzH

Comment: did you try using a SCNTransaction to animate the transform value of your node?

Comment: Can you give to me an example for this problem?

Comment: I wrote an example within an answer. hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code blocks below solved my problem.

```
    let rotation = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-Float(angle.degreesToRadians), 0, 1, 0)
    let newTransform = SCNMatrix4Mult(cubeNode.transform, rotation)
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
    animation.toValue = scene.rootNode.convertTransform(newTransform, from: nil)
    animation.duration = 1.5
    animation.fillMode = .forwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    cubeNode.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code snippet how to work with a `SCNTransaction`. This example has a completion handler. If you don't need this, you can delete the section for the handler.

```
// Scene Transaction with completion handler example
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 6.0

// The completion handling section
SCNTransaction.completionBlock = {
    SCNTransaction.begin()
    SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1.0
    explosion.particleColor = UIColor.blue
    SCNTransaction.commit()
}

cameraNode.camera?.focalLength = 50
SCNTransaction.commit()



// Scene Transaction without completion handler
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 6.0
cameraNode.camera?.focalLength = 50
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

As you can see here, we are modifying the focalLength of a SCNCamera. Try to make a similar adaption for your transform value.